# Why is the recursive step in the divide and conquer matrix multiplication algorithm 8T(n/2) instead of 8T(n/4)

Tags: algorithm, matrix, matrix-multiplication

The D&C matrix multiplication algorithm, C = A * B, assumes A and B are NxN matrices where N is a power of 2. The problem is divided into quarter matrix multiplications for the quarter matrices of the answer C.

```
C11 C12      A11 A12    B11 B12
C21 C22  =   A21 A22  * B21 B22
```

The partition step in the recursive algorithm looks like this

```
C11 = SMMR(A11, B11) + SMMR(A12, B21)
C12 = SMMR(A11, B12) + SMMR(A12, B22)
C21 = SMMR(A21, B11) + SMMR(A22, B21)
C22 = SMMR(A21, B12) + SMMR(A22, B22)
```

The analysis explains this as, each recursive call multiplies two N/2 x N/2 matrices. There are eight calls so 8T(n/2).

My question is, why is this not 8T(n/4) ? I see 8 calls to problems of 1/4 the size of the original problem.

The remainder of the analysis shows that the additions end up being theta(n^2) which I understand and the time complexity is shown as
T(n) = 8T(n/2) + theta(n^2)

Comment: It seems _n_ is the number of rows and columns of the matrices.  The submatrices have _n_ /2 rows and columns.  The number of entries in the submatrices is a quarter of the original number of entries, but the number of row or columns is half the original number. (I presume _n_ and _N_ are the same number.)

Comment: aha, right you are sir!

Answer (score 1):

Answer by Sven Marnach:

> It seems n is the number of rows and columns of the matrices. The
>   submatrices have n / 2 rows and columns. The number of entries in the
>   submatrices is a quarter of the original number of entries, but the
>   number of rows or columns is half the original number. (n and N are
>   the same number.)